# How to link llvm pass to external library?

Tags: llvm-c++-api

I am writing my analysis pass to get the access maps of global arrays in an OpenCL kernel.
I want to perform operations on these maps using the [isl](https://github.com/Meinersbur/isl) library. I've installed the isl library, and I can use it with other C/C++ code by using the `-lisl` option with clang.

What should I add to my `CMakeLists.txt` file to link my pass in `lib/Transforms/MyPass` to the isl library?